# Equivalent of Google Guice Injector in Spring

Tags: spring, guice

At the moment I have some code that uses Google Guice to start a server:

```
   Injector injector = createInjector(
        new Module(root, domain, realm),
        new TestsArtefactsServiceModule()


   final Server server = injector.getInstance(Server.class);
   server.acquire();
   server.activate();
   getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> stopServer(server)));
```

I need to change it to use Spring.

Is there an equivalent of the Guice `Injector` class in Spring? Or, is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In Spring it's the ApplicationContext you are looking for.

There is a comparison of these two frameworks:
http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Comparing-Spring-vs-Google-Guice-By-Example